# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown and breadcrumb not playing together nicely

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used Bootstraps dropdown menus a bunch of times but I'm running into issues using Bootstraps breadcrumb. The dropdown is falling behind the breadcrumb (See picture). I've tried adding a z-index to the dropdown but that didn't work. Any ideas?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="headercontainer">
    <%= link_to image_tag("ep_small.png"), "#", class: 'intlogo' %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Associations", organizations_path %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="false">
                Operations <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Wrap Companies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is the dropdown menu position relative or absolute?

Comment: You need to set display:block; for the opened li.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a css styling issue. When I run the setup as you describe above on an out-of-the-box instance of Bootstrap, the dropdown is not clipped. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XSUV2/12/).

```
<div>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Operations <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Operations 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Operations 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have a style "overflow: hidden;" on your .headercontainer css class. If I add that, I get results similar to the image you posted.

Comment: Thanks it was overflow:hidden on the header